# Binding textboxes to database (C# web developer)

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, binding

I am using Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2010 Express. I have been trying to enter my textbox input into a database table I created. I ran into a problem using the DataBinding property (located under the BindTextBoxes method at the bottom). I searched the internet and found out that the DataBinding property does not exist in Web Developer. Is there an alternate way to transfer the textbox input into a database table?

Here is database part of my code (in C#):

```
    namespace WebApplication2
    {
        public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
        {
     //used to link textboxes with database
     BindingSource bsUserDetails = new BindingSource();

     //info stored in tables
     DataSet dsUserDetails = new DataSet();

     //manages connection between database and application
     SqlDataAdapter daUserDetails = new SqlDataAdapter();

     //create new SQL connection
     SqlConnection connUserDetails = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\Users\synthesis\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Practical\Practical\App_Data\UserDetails.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");

     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         //link textboxes to relevant fields in the dataset
         bsUserDetails.DataSource = dsUserDetails;
         bsUserDetails.DataMember = dsUserDetails.Tables[0].ToString();

         //call BindTextBoxes Method
         BindTextBoxes();

     private void BindTextBoxes()
     {
     txtBoxCell.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Name entered into txtBox", bsUserDetails,              
     "Name column in database table", true));
     }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always write your own SQL for inserting data from your text boxes. You'll need to setup a SqlConnection and SqlCommand object. Then you'll need to define the SQL on the command and set up the parameters to prevent SQL injection. Something like this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("INSERT INTO sometable VALUES(@text1,@text2)");

SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sb.ToString());
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("text1", text1.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("text2", text2.Text);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried to run my project but experience the following error: "Unrecognized escape sequence" for the following line:                       SqlConnection connUserDetails = new SqlConnection("DataSource=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\Users\synthesis\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Practical\Practical\App_Data\UserDetails.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"); I think it had a problem with the forward slash "/" in that line

Comment: put @ before any string in c# containing "\" as in new SqlConnection(@"DataSource...") and that will solve that error